# Standard engagement timeframe in modern Orthodox and Yishivish circles

Tags: shidduchim-dating, social-convention, engagement-shidduch

I am recently new to this shidduchim scene and I am wondering what standard engagement timeframes are for the out-of-town modern orthodox and Yishivish circles. Once a couple becomes engaged how long is it usually until the chupah? It would be useful to know what the standard timeframe both on the long and short sides of the spectrum are. Being someone who lives in a relatively small town (only 250 frum families) and did not grow up orthodox, this topic is relatively new to me.

Comment: How are you planning on using this information? It seems once you're engaged, you should figure out how much time you'll need to prepare for the wedding and allot yourself that much time.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I love the user name you've chosen :) You may want to consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience the average engagement period in the Yeshivish circles is 2 - 4 months. Although I know of cases where the wedding was in as short as 4 -5 weeks and others where it was as much as 6 months.